# Why should one study English in India?

Tags: british-english

I'm a teacher teaching English in a village school.I need a concrete reason to continue to do so.I am looking for opinions,facts,references & even specific expertise.

Comment: Rupees! Are they not paying you, or paying you enough?

Comment: One in ten or maybe only one in 100 of your students will be exceptionally bright and have the potential to go on to much greater things if given the chance.  It's worth it to give that student a chance.

Comment: If you don't enjoy teaching English, if you don't find it fulfilling, if you find your students boring or uninspiring, it's better to quit teaching. Not for your sake but for theirs. Not everyone is cut out to be a teacher, there's no shame in it.

Comment: Is your question as stated in the title: *Why should one* ***study***...*? Or is it as stated in the body: why should you ***continue teaching***? This should be closed as unclear if not clarified, and as primarily opinion-based, if clarified to choose one of the two questions.

Comment: Hey Mari-Lou ! I love teaching kids.I just wanted to clarify some questions in my head therefore I asked the question(I am still exploring the world).

Comment: Hey Drew ! I need to know why I should be teaching English as I need to inform the kids i teach the value of learning English and inspire them to put their minds to learning the language.I apologize if for the confusion.

Comment: Hey Hot Licks ! Thank you for your inspiring words.

Comment: Hey Brian ! I volunteer at a village school in India.

Comment: You might like to post this question on our [sister site ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) where very many of the posters are EFL teachers and quite a few are English language learners from India! :)

Comment: This question is very unlikely to get closed on that site as its about language learning and teaching. (It also has some great writers on it who really know what they're talking about!).

Comment: Then the question should be: How can I inspire my students to learn, study and improve their English? Your: *"I need a concrete reason to continue to do so"* sounds like you're having second thoughts about a career in teaching.

Answer (score 3):

English is one of the two official languages of India, the second being Hindi. If any of your students want a job in any official government post, or a job where they have to deal with the government, speaking English will be a huge advantage to them. Being able to speak any other language is good for ones job prospects, and is in any case a fulfilling enterprise which broadens the mind. English is widely used across the world as a lingua franca. So being able to speak English enables you to communicate with people from many different parts of the world, including many other people for whom English isn't their first language.

Comment: Hey Araucaria ! Thanks for the input.I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The Indian students need to develop the skills of 'speaking English', 'writing English', and 'reading English' to qualify in any kind of Government jobs as well as in the private sector. There are many jobs which have the prime criteria of speaking fluent English, e.g. - in call centres, meeting foreign delegates, presenting projects to international or multinational companies.

But unfortunately English is a bugbear to the students in villages, especially students studying in vernacular-medium schools. So it is very important for them to understand and use the language as easily as their mother tongue. Most teacher who teach English in Indian village schools have learnt English as a 'second language'. If a native speaker of English had taught English, it would have been a different kind of experience.